# Emulate Full Battery Charge

Tags: battery, emulators

Now before you guys disvote this question, let me explain. I've been messing with lithium polymer batteries for 8 years (I work in a shop repairing electronics) and I have studied the behavior of Lithium Polymer batteries.

It kinda bugs me when my phone automatically shuts down when battery level is said to be 0%. In these moments I usually am finishing almost done watching a video or writing up a text to someone and my phone completely interrupts all operations and shuts down. I know for a fact that as when it shuts down there still is enough power left to run the phone for another 4 emergency minutes.

Is there a way I can emulate the operating system into thinking I have a higher percentage of power left so that it wouldn't shut down right away? I know this sounds risky, but I am aware of what's really happening here. My system is Nexus 4 running android 4.4 (fully rooted).

Comment: Not related but I know a trick in old nokia phones. Whenever battery is empty, I will keep an currency note in between the battery and battery pin in the phone and I will pull the currency note and voila phone will survive 5 more minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what it sounds like, you not only want it to show a higher percentage but also 'use' this last little bit of juice in the battery.  Technically you could just modify the icon to show full all the time or be slightly above the real level, but that's just the icon's look.  I think to accomplish what you're trying to do you will have to modify the ROM yourself.  If your savvy in this field, you can look for some open source ROMs, modify it, and see if it works.

Comment: Makes sense. Do you know any roms that do that?

Comment: due to the fact that not many people have the battery experience you do, many ROMs just shut off like the official android ROM.  I haven't heard of a ROM that does this but you could look around xda-developers or try Google to find one.

Answer (score 0):

I have a rooted GS2 and I installed "Xposer Installer" and within that program I installed the "Xposed framework" that lets you download "tweaks" for android.

http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer

I didn't try it, but among the available tweaks there is one named "DisableCriticalBatteryShutdown".

The description says:

> DisableCriticalBatteryShutdown (for Xposed Framework)
>
> What?
>
> Disables the Auto-Shutdown when Android detects a critical
>   battery level
>
> Why?
>
> This is to prevent the auto-shutdown when you have 1% left of
>   battery. It is useful for calibrating your battery by draining it
>   completely, using Chinese Branded Batteries with terrible battery
>   percentage detection or even lengthen the life of a phone with
>   non-removable battery with terrible calibration.
>
> Compatiblility: Not working on 4.3+ Tested only on AOSP 2.3, 4.0, 4.1
>
> This project is abandoned, I will not add support for any other ROMs.

As I already said, I haven't tested it, but theres a chance that it does what it says.  If you have 4.1 or older this might do what you need.

Comment: Just installed the app, now it says that it soesnt work on 4.3+ and i have 4.4

Comment: the "not working on 4.3+" means anythiong higher than 4.3 or 4.3 and higher. i might downgrade